# Confusion about coefficients of logistic regression model produced by glm(family = binomial) in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interpretation

I have a response variable that is binary ( 1 - recovered, 0 - dead) and I will use two predictor variables as an example. One is continuous (age) and one is binary ( condition x: ( 1 - patient has it, 0 - patient doesn't have it)). I use glm() function in R, specifying the family = "binomial". It gives out some parameters and then I use odds.ratio function to get the exponentiate values ( as the function summary(model) gives out the log values). The coefficient for age is equal to 1.26. Previously, I'd interpret it as for every y aged patient that dies there are 1.26 (y+1) aged patients that die. Now, I understand that this is incorrect, as this is not linear model, so how do I interpret the coefficient in this instance?

Then I have binary predictor (1 - has a condition x, 0 - doesn't have a condition). For this variable I get a coefficient of 0.13. This is absurd, because it can be interpreted as for every one patient, that doesn't have condition x and dies, there are 0.13x patients that has the condition x and dies. But from the sample, which I used to make the model it is obvious that the condition x has a negative influence on death rates. From the 143 that recovered, there are 83 patients, that had the condition, i.e., roughly 58% of recovered patients had the condition. From the 92 patients that died, 54 had the condition, i.e., 59 %..  So, the coefficient should be close to zero. I don't understand how can I interpret the coefficient 0.13 in this case. Please advice!

Here is a data frame where you can see the outcome and the number of cases that have this outcome and number of cases that have this outcome and has a condition x:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   outcome, age group [13]
   outcome   `age group`     n `condition x`
   <chr>     <fct>       <int>         <dbl>
 1 recovered 21-30           3             0
 2 recovered 31-40           8             0
 3 dead      31-40           2             1
 4 recovered 41-50          21            10
 5 dead      41-50           2             1
 6 recovered 51-60          36            17
 7 dead      51-60          17            10
 8 recovered 61-70          47            31
 9 dead      61-70          23             9
10 recovered 71-80          18            17
11 dead      71-80          21            16
12 recovered 81+            10             8
13 dead      81+            27            17
```

Here is the summary of the model, the variables that I referred to before are age and AH:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Izn ~ ., family = "binomial", data = myData14)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.00942  -0.20697  -0.01299   0.00155   2.62596  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.868e+01  4.508e+00  -4.144 3.41e-05 ***
DZ           9.712e-01  7.510e-01   1.293 0.195917    
age          2.309e-01  6.039e-02   3.824 0.000131 ***
DS           1.754e-01  1.117e-01   1.570 0.116412    
DSCOv        2.290e-02  8.376e-02   0.273 0.784534    
ITP          2.131e+00  1.256e+00   1.696 0.089918 .  
Ran          3.660e+01  2.778e+03   0.013 0.989491    
MPV                 NA         NA      NA       NA    
ECMO        -1.244e+01  1.228e+04  -0.001 0.999191    
NIV          5.427e+00  2.032e+00   2.671 0.007558 ** 
APNK         4.033e+00  1.494e+00   2.699 0.006954 ** 
CD          -1.546e+00  9.272e-01  -1.668 0.095382 .  
AH          -2.018e+00  8.602e-01  -2.346 0.018975 *  
HSM          2.406e+00  9.568e-01   2.515 0.011917 *  
HNM          1.720e+00  1.508e+00   1.140 0.254092    
HOPS        -8.647e-02  1.309e+00  -0.066 0.947332    
BA          -5.312e+00  5.962e+00  -0.891 0.373010    
PON          1.342e+01  1.242e+04   0.001 0.999138    
CON          1.717e+00  1.182e+00   1.453 0.146330    
adipoz      -1.276e+00  1.394e+00  -0.915 0.359956    
imunsu      -2.467e+01  1.935e+03  -0.013 0.989829    
aritm       -2.461e+00  1.027e+00  -2.396 0.016583 *  
KSS         -2.394e+00  1.410e+00  -1.698 0.089557 .  
VecsMI      -7.145e-01  1.563e+00  -0.457 0.647548    
JaunsMI      1.734e+00  1.341e+00   1.292 0.196197    
PCI         -1.366e+00  1.298e+00  -1.052 0.292592    
aknuboj      1.297e+00  1.339e+00   0.969 0.332683    
anemija     -2.841e-01  2.770e+00  -0.103 0.918300    
akCI         7.927e-01  1.375e+00   0.577 0.564229    
vecsCI       5.050e+00  1.606e+00   3.145 0.001660 ** 
pate         1.223e+00  2.214e+00   0.552 0.580868    
citaAvS      3.499e-01  1.355e+00   0.258 0.796248    
end          8.812e-01  2.879e+00   0.306 0.759529    
transpl      1.779e+00  1.784e+04   0.000 0.999920    
citaP        3.239e+00  1.806e+00   1.794 0.072882 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 314.623  on 234  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  78.696  on 201  degrees of freedom
AIC: 146.7

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19
```

One person commented, that age most probably doesn't influence the outcome linearly, so I cut the age in several groups. All the coefficients for the age groups are not significant:

```
Call:
glm(formula = Izn ~ ., family = "binomial", data = myData14)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.19606  -0.18729  -0.00002   0.00117   2.56960  

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    -2.876e+01  1.439e+04  -0.002  0.99841   
DZ              8.621e-01  8.011e-01   1.076  0.28186   
DS              1.464e-01  1.154e-01   1.269  0.20457   
DSCOv           3.422e-02  1.035e-01   0.331  0.74085   
ITP             2.469e+00  1.615e+00   1.528  0.12639   
Ran             5.537e+01  4.960e+03   0.011  0.99109   
MPV                    NA         NA      NA       NA   
ECMO           -1.491e+01  1.784e+04  -0.001  0.99933   
NIV             5.852e+00  2.403e+00   2.435  0.01490 * 
APNK            3.804e+00  1.837e+00   2.070  0.03841 * 
CD             -1.753e+00  1.074e+00  -1.633  0.10249   
AH             -2.323e+00  1.005e+00  -2.313  0.02074 * 
HSM             2.525e+00  9.798e-01   2.578  0.00995 **
HNM             1.535e+00  1.611e+00   0.953  0.34062   
HOPS            2.038e-01  1.323e+00   0.154  0.87755   
BA             -4.108e+00  4.226e+00  -0.972  0.33099   
PON             1.348e+01  1.976e+04   0.001  0.99946   
CON             1.475e+00  1.233e+00   1.196  0.23166   
adipoz         -2.026e-01  1.579e+00  -0.128  0.89793   
imunsu         -2.555e+01  3.003e+03  -0.009  0.99321   
aritm          -2.813e+00  1.155e+00  -2.435  0.01490 * 
KSS            -2.389e+00  1.473e+00  -1.622  0.10486   
VecsMI         -9.956e-01  1.686e+00  -0.591  0.55484   
JaunsMI         1.739e+00  1.406e+00   1.236  0.21628   
PCI            -1.836e+00  1.354e+00  -1.356  0.17502   
aknuboj         9.871e-01  1.514e+00   0.652  0.51449   
anemija        -1.314e+00  2.705e+00  -0.486  0.62725   
akCI            6.122e-01  1.420e+00   0.431  0.66647   
vecsCI          5.408e+00  1.806e+00   2.995  0.00275 **
pate            1.285e+00  2.442e+00   0.526  0.59871   
citaAvS        -3.175e-01  1.726e+00  -0.184  0.85407   
end            -1.048e+00  3.988e+00  -0.263  0.79264   
transpl        -1.461e+01  2.950e+04   0.000  0.99960   
citaP           4.619e+00  2.298e+00   2.010  0.04446 * 
age_group31-40  4.930e+00  2.085e+04   0.000  0.99981   
age_group41-50  3.876e+00  1.462e+04   0.000  0.99979   
age_group51-60  2.353e+01  1.439e+04   0.002  0.99870   
age_group61-70  2.461e+01  1.439e+04   0.002  0.99864   
age_group71-80  2.839e+01  1.439e+04   0.002  0.99843   
age_group81+    3.059e+01  1.439e+04   0.002  0.99830   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 314.623  on 234  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  71.466  on 196  degrees of freedom
AIC: 149.47

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 20
```

Maybe I've done the cut incorrectly? What's the reason the age when cut in groups is no longer significant?
The question about the coefficient for AH ( condition x, that I spoke of before) still remains. It doesn't make sense that the coefficient equals exp(-2.323e+00) = 0.09. From there it could be concluded that patients that have AH are much less likely die, which as I pointed out above, is not true.
Here is the table, where you can see the count of cases of all possible combinations of outcomes and AH ( outcome = 0 => recovered, 1 => dead; AH = 0 => doesn't have the condition AH, 1 => has the condition AH). So all the cases where outcome = 0 equals 143, from those 83 had the condition AH, so the recovery proportion is 83/143 = 58%. From all the cases where outcome = 1, 54 patients had AH. So, the rate equals 54/92 = 58%.

```
  outcome AH count
1       0  0    60
2       1  0    38
3       0  1    83
4       1  1    54
```

Comment: Interpreting odds ratios as relative risks is a cardinal rookie mistake. Surely this is a repeat question. The coefficient 0.13 for `x` seems like you haven't exponentiated it yet. Once you do, the interpretation is that the odds for recovery are approx 15% higher for patients with the condition adjusting for age.

Comment: @AdamO That's the problem, it is already exponentiated. I don't know what the problem could be...

Comment: So the *coefficient* is not 0.13 as you have said, but the *odds ratio* is 0.013 ( the coefficient must be approx -4). Inspect a simple $2 \times 2$ table, possibly broken out by a couple age groups to confirm your findings.

Comment: @AdamO The coefficient is approximately -2 and exp(-2) =  0.13. I added a data frame, where you can see the number of cases of outcome per age group and the corresponding number of cases that have the condition x.

Comment: If the range of `age` values is large, it is a strong assumption to assume `age` has a linear effect. Maybe spline it?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual `summary` of the model results (intercept, coefficients, standard errors), to avoid any potential misunderstandings about what's been exponentiated and what hasn't. When I get confused about these things (which still happens to me), I find it's best to get back to the original coefficients and work systematically forward from there. Also, you might find it easier to interpret coefficients if you reverse your coding of the outcome to 1=dead/0=recovered, to match the standard R coding of "events" (deaths) in survival analysis.

Comment: @EdM So, I updated my post. I have already coded the outcome like you said: 1 = dead, 0 = recovered. Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen You are right, the age probably doesn't have a linear effect. I cut the age into several groups, but no the coefficients to no group are significant. What could be the issue?

Comment: The next problem is that you are overfitting: with 92 cases in the minority-outcome class, you shouldn't be evaluating more than about 6 predictors in your model (usual rule of thumb, 10-20 minority-class members per predictor). You have nearly 40 predictors. Next, binning by age can be inefficient as it adds many extra predictors. A flexible spline fit to `age` should handle non-linearities much more efficiently. Please edit this question to show a minimal model that brings out specifically your confusion about how to interpret logistic regression coefficients, and read up on overfitting.

Comment: @EdM Ok, but how do I choose the predictors that could be used for the model? Should I just take the ones, that are more significant in this overfitted model?

Comment: Separate out your question here about how to interpret logistic regression coefficients from the broader question of how to design regression models. For the first question, just edit this question to show a model with a few predictors that lead to your confusion about how to interpret the coefficients. It won't matter whether that's your final model or not; the point is to make sure that you know how to interpret the coefficients correctly. For the second question, how to model your data, get and study [Frank Harrell's course notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf), especially Chapter 4.